# Data fetching in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have some questions regarding data fetching in the new Next.js 13 app directory.

Server actions and route handlers seem rather similar. I have heard them both described as an API, and seen them queried from [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info). They also both have a method to invalidate the data. So here are my questions:

1. What are the key differences between server actions and route handlers?
2. The Next.js documentation state that the invalidation methods (tag and path) simply invalidate the cache, but only when the request is made again. In a practical sense, this means the page will only reflect the data change on reload. How exactly do I refresh the data on the page when invalidating? Particularly without an entire page refresh?
3. Since server actions and route handlers are technically APIs and you can interact directly with your database, does it make sense for me to use them? My particular use case is that I already have built out an external API to interact with my database. Does it make sense to call my external API in server actions and route handlers? It seems like a needless middleman API.
4. Regarding question 3, would it make more sense to call my external API from server components? Do I lose any key feature if I don't use server actions or route handlers? Specifically, the invalidation techniques (path and tag) seem to be specifically for route handlers and server actions (according to the Next.js documentation); so, if I *do* call my API from a server component, how does invalidation and page refresh work?